# How to validate KeyboardEvent values for a number input?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, keyboard-events

I am having an input of type number. Chromium browsers seems to restrict the input too, however firefox doesn't and this is a problem (for our product managers).
So I figured out, why not filtering while having an input via an event like Keydown, Keyup or Keypress.

I first made this function to filter my input:

```
public filterInput(event: KeyboardEvent){
    //ignore all characters that are not numbers, except backspace, delete, left arrow and right arrow
    if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) && event.keyCode != 8 && event.keyCode != 46 && event.keyCode != 37 && event.keyCode != 39) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

However I am thinking of generalizing this function and make it something like this

```
public filterInput(event: KeyboardEvent, regExPattern: string | RegExp){
    const keyCodesArray: Array<number> = [..., 8, 46, 37, 39]; //get all possible keyCodes in that pattern + allow right/left arrows, backspace and delete
    //check whether keycode is included or not. 
    if (!keyCodesArray.includes(event.keyCode)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

After searching and digging into it I came up with such a general function:

```
public filterInput(event: KeyboardEvent, regEx: RegExp){
    const restrict = !regEx.test(event.key) && event.key != "Backspace" && event.key !== "ArrowLeft" && event.key !== "ArrowRight" && event.key !== "Delete";
    if (restrict){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

My concerns are that the performance might be bad or is there any exceptions I might missing. Also I dont really like the idea of comparing with strings (Backspace, Delete, ArrowLeft and ArrowRight).

Is there any thinkable but also useful and better way to do this? or should I just stick to my function above.

Happy to hear your suggestions.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, but I still would like to know if it is possible to convert a pattern to an array of keycodes. I was just showing that I tried something and not asking people to do my work, cause me being lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Don't** use [`ev.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)
- **Don't** use a blacklist filter (any value is allowed, *except* `x`, `y`, `z`...)

---

- **Do** use [`ev.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)
- **Do** use a whitelist filter (the *only* values allowed are `a`, `b`, `c`...)

---

Suggestions:

- Use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of valid `ev.key` values:

  ```ts
  if (!set.has(ev.key)) ev.preventDefault();
  ```
- If you are concerned about string type validation for comparisons with `ev.key`, you can test values [here](https://keycode.info/) and create a [string enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums) or [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#unions) of string literals for use in your program.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But also, do you know how to make an array of keyCodes by a regEx pattern?

Comment: @MrJami Sure: [`regexp.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/toString) and then parse the string (probably using another regex ). (It's much easier to build a regex from other data structures than to parse one.)